# Exporting out a portion of a directory tree - cvs

Tags: export, cvs

I have the following project structure:

```
~/projects:
dir1/  dir2/ dir3/ .... dirn/

dir1/:
dir11/  dir12/  ... dir1n/
```

I want to export all directories `dir2/` to `dirn/` from within `~/projects` and only `dir11/` from within `dir1/`. How do I do this? I am using `cvs`.

Thanks,
Sriram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVS doesn't have a method (that I can find or have ever heard of) to exclude certain modules on export (or checkout).

You'll have to do it in two steps

```
cvs ex -r HEAD dir1/dir11 dir2 dir3 ... dirn
mv dir1/dir11 . ; rmdir dir1
```

Not sure if the `mv` and `rmdir` commands are what you want to do, but the gist of it is, exporting `dir1/dir11` is going to create a `dir1/` folder, which I'm assuming you don't want.

Otherwise, export `dir11/` in a separate command with the `-d` option, something like:

```
cvs ex -r HEAD dir2 dir3 ... dirn
cvs ex -r HEAD -d dir11 dir1/dir11
```